# Is the new C# async feature implemented strictly in the compiler

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, clr, async-await

As a C# programmer whose interested in exploring "how things work", i am interested in understanding a bit more about the process that makes the new *async* feature work.

I have followed Eric Lippert's excellent article series on async: [Async blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/async/)

I don't remember seeing anywhere any reference to the implementation of this feature (in a high level) except for the fact the the "compiler is doing most of the work" for us.

Is this feature strictly a compiler feature then? does the compiler rewrite the code in some manner and that's it? or are there other things like runtime support that make this happen?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, it's not *entirely* in the compiler. It relies on some new interfaces such as [`INotifyCompletion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.inotifycompletion.aspx) and some framework *implementation* support such as [`AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh138506.aspx). I don't believe there are any CLR changes required though.

The compiler does a lot of work, building a state machine - it just refers to a few of those types within the state machine. Oh, and a lot of the `Task`-related types were significantly modified primarily for performance reasons.

I have a [series of blog posts](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Eduasync/default.aspx) which were initially written against the CTP but *only* using vanilla .NET 4 and some classes I whipped up myself. They won't work against the production implementation (as things changed a bit over time) but they'll give you a general impression of what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: FGITW backed up with a *series* of blog posts.  Hard not to upvote that.  I'm still working through your Edulinq series.

Comment: I don't recall there being any changes to the CLR but I was not following that closely. Stephen would know for sure.

Comment: @EricLippert: Given the [async targeting pack](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) for earlier versions it would at least make things tricky. Of course there may have been optimizations to make it *better* on the 4.5 CLR :)

Comment: @EricLippert do you mean Stephen Toub? and Jon - a targeting pack consists of changes to the framework?compiler? runtime? how does it help determining whether there were CLR changes or not?

Comment: @lysergic-acid The targeting pack is a library that makes the new compiler features work on older version of the framework. That means `async`-`await` can work without CLR changes in .Net 4.5 (if there were any).

Comment: @lysergic-acid: Yes, Stephen Toub. Jon's point is that if there were CLR changes *required* to make async work then it would be very difficult to make a *library* that enables async on a previous version. The existence of such a library is evidence that there were no CLR changes.