# Strange debugger behaviour in async method

Tags: c#, debugging, asynchronous, return, throw

When I stepped over breakpoints in my code I have encountered strange behaviour of debugger:

```
public async Task DoSomeWork()
{
     await Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); });

     var test = false;
     if (test)
     {
          throw new Exception("Im in IF body!");
     }
}
```

Debugger goes into `if` body. It's remarkable that the exception is not really thrown but just looks like it is. So you can't reproduce that if you place breakpoint right on `throw`. You must place it above and step down to the `if` body to catch it. The same works on any kind of exception instance (as well as explicit `null`) and even on `return` instead of `throw`.

Besides that it works even if I remove line with `await`.

I tried to run this code snippet from different PCs so its not a PC trouble. Also I have thought it is bug in VS code and tried to run it in Rider from JetBrains - the same result.

I'm sure it's the async thing but how it explicitly works?

Comment: I filed a bug report with Microsoft just now, including [this dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42539388/1132334) and a screenshot from my own IDE to prove that disassembly and C# source view instruction pointers do not match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code reproduces the issue easily, in a *"Debug"* build, using Visual Studio 2015. I had only to add in `Program.Main()`, with a call to `DoSomeWork().Wait();`, set a breakpoint in the method and step through it.

As for why it happens, this is undoubtedly due to the combination of the `async` method being rewritten and the debugging database (.pdb) generated. Similar to iterator methods, adding `async` to the method causes the compiler to change your method into a state machine. The actual IL that's generated looks only a little bit like the original method. That is, if you look at it, you can identify the key components of the original code, but it's now in a big `switch` statement that handles what happens as the method returns at each `await` statement, and then is re-entered with the completion of each awaited expression.

When the program statement appears to be on the `throw`, it's really at the implicit `return` statement in the method. It's just that the debugging database for the executable doesn't provide a program statement for that line.

There's a hint, when debugging, that that's what's happening. When you step over the `if` statement, you'll notice it goes straight to the `throw` statement. If the `if` statement block were *really* being entered, the next program statement line would actually be the opening brace for the block, not the program statement.

You can also add e.g. a `Console.WriteLine()` at the end of the method, and that will give the debugger enough information to sync up and not show you at the wrong line number.

For additional information on how `async` methods are handled by the compiler, see [Is the new C# async feature implemented strictly in the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15349287), and the links provided there (including Jon's series of articles on the topic).

Comment: You said 'adding `async` and at least one `await`', but I reproduced that even without line with `await` at all

Comment: @Altav1sta: okay, then it seems the compiler generates the state machine for all `async` methods. I interpreted "it works" in your post to mean that the debugger did the _right_ thing, not the wrong thing. I guess that's not what you meant.

Comment: Yes, sorry for confusing. I meant __it works same__ i.e. I enter `if` body but exception is not really thrown